# Message Archive Management is not supported by: MongooseIM doesn't return MAM feature if LocalAndDomainJID provided

Tags: mongoose-im

In smack xmpp java client serviceDiscoveryManager.discoverInfo in case of LocalAndDomainpartJID provided returns 20 features without MAM feature. Total 20 features only.
If I provide only DomainpartJid I am able to see two MAM features with different versions. Total 60 features.

My mongooseim.toml snippet is

```
[modules.mod_mam]
  archive_chat_markers = true
  pm.backend = "rdbms"
  backend = "rdbms"
  pm.user_prefs_store = "mnesia"
  muc.user_prefs_store = "mnesia"
```

And how could I receive features using mongooseimctl command?

My kotlin code connection:

```
val config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .setUsernameAndPassword("a519-286", "*****")
        .setXmppDomain("msg.***.com")
        .setHost("msg.***.com")
        .build()

val connection: AbstractXMPPConnection = XMPPTCPConnection(config)
connection.connect() 
connection.login()

val mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection)
    println ("is supported :" + mamManager.isSupported)

//false
    println ("namespace: " + mamManager.mamNamespace)
//null
```

Comment: One of the MongooseIM core team members has let me know that he asked on GitHub for more information to troubleshoot the problem: https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/issues/4106

It would help the team a lot if you could provide the needed information. Otherwise, they might not be able to help.